# How to get hour and minutes difference from two localtime joda

Tags: java, math, jodatime

I want to get the difference between two LocalTime values in hours and minutes?
Suppose i want the time difference between 6pm and 11.59 am, ie, 5.59 (5 hours and 59minutes).

```
LocalTime startTimeOnlyEST = new LocalTime(startTimeEST);
LocalTime endTimeOnlyEST = new LocalTime(endTimeEST);

float quotient = Minutes.minutesBetween(startTimeOnlyEST,       endTimeOnlyEST).getMinutes() / 60;
```

By using the above code, we get only the hour value 5..I want to get .59 also.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int total_minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(startTimeOnlyEST, endTimeOnlyEST).getMinutes();
int hours = total_minutes / 60;
int minutes = total_minutes % 60;
```